# Ubuntu undefined symbol: _XGetRequest

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I've installed `mednafen` emulator in my Ubuntu 12.04, the thing is every time I try to run the game, it crashes with `mednafen: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest`

How can I solve this??

Comment: From where did you get `mednafen` and how did you install it? It is definite that the version you installed was build for a different set of libraries than you have on your computer.

Comment: @DanD. with the software center...